# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Getting a `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` mysql error whenever I try to insert into the table `sets`.

I googled and found a hoard of similar questions but they are always pin point specific to solving their immediate problem. I have mysql 5.6 by the way. I am allowed multiple TIMESTAMPS.

**Here is my code:**

```
INSERT INTO `sets` (`tabler_name`) VALUES ("leads_auto");
```

**Here is my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lms`.`sets` (
    `set_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `on_off` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `tabler_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `origin_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_modified_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `original_count` INT NULL,
    `current_count` INT NULL,
    `source_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `source` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `method` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `agent` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `dupes` INT NULL,
    `bads` INT NULL,
    `aged` INT NULL COMMENT 'This table keeps track of the record sets that enter the system.        Example: a set of leads imported into the database.',
    PRIMARY KEY (`set_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `lms`.`leads_to_bak` ()
BEGIN
SET @table1 = (SELECT `tabler_name` FROM sets WHERE on_off=0 LIMIT 1);
SET @table2 = CONCAT(@table1, '_bak');
SET @SQL1 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@table2, '(', (SELECT
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2), ')', ' SELECT ', (SELECT                                                                   REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'lead_id,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE       TABLE_NAME = @table1), ' FROM ', @table1);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt;
END//

DELIMITER ;
USE `lms`;
```

**Trigger**

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `lms`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `lms`.`after_insert_into_leads`
AFTER INSERT ON `sets` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT * FROM sets WHERE on_off=0 LIMIT 1) THEN
CALL lms.leads_to_bak();
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
USE `lms`;
```

I don't see anything wrong with my routines. Removing the routines and trigger seems to make the problem go away.

Comment: I am not able to create this table for myself. it says: "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause."?

Comment: I have mysql 5.6 which allows for multiple TIMESTAMP columns. Previous versions do not.

Comment: As stated [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,400104,400115#msg-400115), it is a [subquery error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-errors.html). Are you positive you are getting it from the said INSERT statement?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Apparently it happens whenever I insert into other columns as well.. But after running a few test inserts the problem seems to only exist in the table `sets`... I have a trigger attached to that table that calls a stored procedure. I'll post it now.

Comment: Just to clarify: you've already looked into that stored procedure and couldn't understand if or why it could produce the error and that's why you are going to post it (the SP) for our attention, right?

Comment: I'm looking into it now. If I can't figure it out then i'll resort to posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your trigger, did you mean to put `EXISTS` after `IF`? Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `lms`.`after_insert_into_leads`
AFTER INSERT ON `sets` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sets WHERE on_off=0 LIMIT 1) THEN
CALL lms.leads_to_bak();
END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape your table name, it seems to be a reserved function. I'm not sure if you've defined one locally.

```
INSERT INTO `sets` (tabler_name) VALUES ("leads_auto");
```

Also, you can't have two timestamp fields in a single database afaik. Change one of the two timestamps to a DATETIME field if it caused you issues as well

Answer (score 0):

Besides escaping the field name in your `INSERT`-statement, it cannot be improved very much. But it doesn't generate any error in my test enviroment. Is this really the exact statement throwing you an error?

However, there's a slight problem in your table definition, it will throw you an

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column
>   with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause.

As the error message indicates, you can only use one `timestamp` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, if you need more than one, you can do this using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).